# What was Grant Holloways top speed in his 12.81s 110m hurdle run using kinematics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, everyday-life, biophysics

I am a currently a introductory biophysics student and I am attempting to analyze Grant Holloway's 12.81s 110m hurdle run. I thought the best approach would be to break the run into stages due to the variance in acceleration that runners undergo. I started by attempting to analyze the "acceleration phase" or the phase where the runner is approaching the first hurdle. However, I achieved an answer that would essentially crown Grant Holloway as the fastest man alive. Here is my work and the video I used to determine the time:

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMldLl1bWGA

Comment: I think this is not correct approach, you should get data of distance ran vs time or speed vs time and then plot them, by taking derivative of distance vs time graph on various points you can find min and max speed during run, also you can find acceleration at various instants, mistake you did was acceleration you got was average acceleration and v calculated was speed attained by that 'constant' acceleration after given time, hence you are getting error in your result.